# How to set variables from a Firebase snapshot (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to grab the data from my Firebase snapshot and set it to variables in my Project. I get the data, but I don't know how to parse it so I can set them. I'm trying to do something like what SwiftyJSON does with API calls.

### Here is my data structure in firebase: [image: data structure]

### Here is my function: [image: function]

### Here is the output in the console: [image: output]

Is there any way to parse and set values from the (ls) array and set the  "fromId", "text", "toId" to different variables for each node?

Comment: Post you code as text not snippet

Comment: An important point to note is that the returned snapshot is not an *array*, it's a *Dictionary* so the order the data is not guaranteed (technically FIRDataSnapshot). You can use .orderBy to set the order with Firebase or sort it in code if ordering is important. The Firebase documentation covers how to parse the data in a Snapshot [Read & Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write). Although the docs are not currently very Swifty, apply the practice in @Dravidian answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/userID/ls").observeSingleEvent(of : .value, with : {(Snap) in 

  if let snapDict = Snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

      for each in snapDict{

           print("\(each.value["fromId"] as! String)")

         }
   }
})
```

Comment: For Swift 3, you will need to unwrap Snap, so it would be be Snap?.value

Comment: @Jay i think not,Infact Compiler asks me to remove the optional `?`

Comment: @Davidian Wow - interesting. Xcode was flagging Snap but the error was actually a typo:  *observerSingleEvent* should be *observeSingleEvent*. I retract my comment and I fixed the code in your answer. (and upvoted for a solid answer!)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast the FIRDataSnapshot value into a [String:Any] dictionary and then access the values using the "fromId", "text", and "toId" keys and assign those values to variables.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be: [SnapshotParser](https://github.com/Appyx/SnapshotParser)

Just implement your classes:

```
func main(){
    let users=SnapshotParser().parseAsList(snap: Snapshot, type: User.self)
    for user in users{
        //do something with your object
    }
}

class User: ParsableSnapshot {
    var id:String?=nil
    var email:String?=nil
    var ls:[Ls]?=nil

    required init(){}

    func bindProperties(binder: SnapshotParser.Binder) {
        binder.bindField(name: "id", field: &id)
        binder.bindField(name: "email", field: &email)
        binder.bindList(name: "ls", list: &ls)
    }
}

class Ls: ParsableSnapshot {
    var id:String?=nil
    var fromId:String?=nil
    var text:String?=nil
    var told:String?=nil

    required init(){}

    func bindProperties(binder: SnapshotParser.Binder) {
        binder.bindField(name: "id", field: &id)
        binder.bindField(name: "fromId", field: &fromId)
        binder.bindField(name: "text", field: &text)
        binder.bindField(name: "told", field: &told)
    }
}
```